# BizTalk XML to EDIFACT EDI assembler hitting exception

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi, edifact

I am currently trying to convert a XML file using XSLT to a EDIFACT format file. 
Translation phase seems to be fine. By using a passthru send port i am able to obtain the EDIFACT file in XML format. However, once I try to pass the file to EDISend pipeline the I am hitting the exception

> Error details: "Delimiter Set could not be read from the interchange. The attribute DelimiterSetSerializedData is missing from root node"

For this particular translation I am using EdifactInterchangeXml as the target schema.

Within the XSLT itself i have also declared the following segments:

```
  <ex0:EdifactInterchangeXml DelimiterSetSerializedData="39:-1:-1:43:58:63:42:44:-1" xmlns:ex0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/Edifact">
    <!--UNB-->
    <ex1:UNB xmlns:ex1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/EdifactServiceSchema">
      <UNB1>
        <UNB1.1><xsl:text>UNOA</xsl:text></UNB1.1>
        <UNB1.2><xsl:text>1</xsl:text></UNB1.2>
      </UNB1>
      <UNB2>
        <UNB2.1><xsl:text>PSA</xsl:text></UNB2.1>
      </UNB2>
      <UNB3>
        <UNB3.1><xsl:value-of select="userCSharp:Mandatory(substring($Desc_COMMID,1,35))"/></UNB3.1>
      </UNB3>
      <UNB4>
        <UNB4.1><xsl:value-of select="substring($DT,3,6)"/></UNB4.1>
        <UNB4.2><xsl:value-of select="substring($DT,9,4)"/></UNB4.2>
      </UNB4>
      <UNB5><xsl:text>(EBP)001</xsl:text></UNB5>
      <xsl:if test="$Desc_COMMID">
        <UNB10><xsl:value-of select="substring($Desc_COMMID,1,35)"/></UNB10>
      </xsl:if>
    </ex1:UNB>
    <ex2:TransactionSetGroup xmlns:ex2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/Edifact">
      <ex3:TransactionSet DocType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/EDIFACT/2006#EFACT_1911_BAPLIE" xmlns:ex3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/Edifact">
        <ns0:EFACT_1911_BAPLIE>
          <!--UNH-->
          <UNH>
            <UNH1><xsl:text>(EBP)0001</xsl:text></UNH1>
            <UNH2>
              <UNH2.1><xsl:text>BAPLIE</xsl:text></UNH2.1>
              <UNH2.2><xsl:text>1</xsl:text></UNH2.2>
              <UNH2.3><xsl:text>911</xsl:text></UNH2.3>
              <UNH2.4><xsl:text>UN</xsl:text></UNH2.4>
              <UNH2.5><xsl:text>SMDG15</xsl:text></UNH2.5>
            </UNH2>
          </UNH>
```

Any suggestion what could have caused the above error?

Comment: It basically means that it wants the UNA segment.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ex0:EdifactInterchangeXml DelimiterSetSerializedData="39:-1:-1:43:58:63:42:44:-1" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/EDIFACT/2006" xmlns:ex0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/tet"><ex5:UNA xmlns:ex5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/EdifactServiceSchema"><UNA1>58</UNA1><UNA2>43</UNA2><UNA3>44</UNA3><UNA4>63</UNA4><UNA5>42</UNA5><UNA6>39</UNA6></ex5:UNA><ex1:UNB xmlns:ex1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Edi/EdifactServiceSchema">` I have tried to include the UNA segment however it is still not working.

Comment: yes still getting the same error message.

Comment: if you another interface producing edifact files perhaps you can view the message it's sending (before the conversion to flat file) and see what you're missing by comparison